# Squid proxy loading from the localhost web server

Tags: networking, proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I've just set up a squid transparent proxy inside my network. The proxy works fine, however it seems some sort of caching policy is causing the proxy to instead go grab a copy of the website, it's simply pointing to 127.0.0.1's HTTP web server (which is NGINX with multiple virtual hosts).

Now this only happens after a site has been visited multiple times, hence why I believe it's a caching issue. I'm wondering now; does Squid have a builtin cache which points to port 80? if so, can i change the port to an alternative and simply set up a virtual site for it? OR is it something completely different that I've overlooked?

Below is a screenshot of the 127.0.0.1 server 404'ing because the directory couldn't be found on the local machine. If I changed directory to "mediawiki.org", it would show me the default website index.html page for my server.

[image: 404 screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration can be help you, and ask me in my question [Squid squidGuard on Debian 6](https://serverfault.com/questions/475434/squid-squidguard-on-debian-6)